# Debug PHPUnit on PhpStorm with MAMP

Tags: symfony, phpunit, phpstorm

I'd like to use breakpoint when use phpunit file. My project is a Symfony project and I use MAMP Pro 3.2.1

This is my configuration:

[image]

When I launch the Debug mode ( with the green bug in the top bar of PhpStorm) I receive this output:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --configuration "/Users/bob/Documents/Lavori Personali/webCamBundle/app/phpunit.xml.dist" Barno\WebcamBundle\Tests\Controller\WebcamControllerTest "/Users/bob/Documents/Lavori Personali/webCamBundle/src/Barno/WebcamBundle/Tests/Controller/WebcamControllerTest.php"
Testing started at 14:03 ...

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Also if I use Breakpoint in my code

[image]

I checked the error on file and I found this

```
    [02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 49
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:209
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::detectPHPUnitVersionId() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:196
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Runner/Version.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/lib/php') in /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php on line 49
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Stack trace:
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   1. {main}() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:0
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   2. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::init() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:209
[02-Jun-2015 14:26:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP   3. IDE_PHPUnit_Loader::detectPHPUnitVersionId() /private/var/folders/0h/tzk_113d4_lcd6rf_bzwjmhr0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php:196
```

Comment: **1)** PhpStorm version? **2)** PHPUnit version **3)** PHPUnit installation type (Composer/PHAR/etc) ?

Comment: phpStorm 8.0.3
PHPUnit 4.3.5 via composer

Comment: How did you configured PHPUnit in PhpStorm? Screenshots please.

Answer (score 0):

- install xdebug module
- check which PHP version are you using

  - php --ini
- setup the IDE settings

  - preference > languages and framework > PHP >

    - set the language level to the correct PHP version of this project
    - set an interpreter (set the parent directory of where the bin directory of PHP executable is loaded)

      - click the … button > click the + button > other local > set PHP Excitable path,

to find the path type in the terminal: $ which php

example: /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.5/bin/php

**restart phpstorm**

- now let’s make it work

  - run > edit configuration > click the green + button on the left > select **php web application**
  - name: anything example ur {application name - debugger}
  - server: localhost (browse > + > name: whatever | host: localhost or 127.0.0.1)
  - click ok
  - start url: the link of ur project homepage:    http://127.0.0.1:80/SomethingNew/
  - click ok
- now set the break point and click debug

Comment: I Want to use phpUnit, no simple debug